# NPE when configuring PostgreSQL DataSource in Equinox

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, osgi

I have the following DataSource configuration file for PAX:

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo
dataSourceName=demo-pg
user=demo
password=demo
```

It creates DataSource in Karaf, however, in Eclipse, using Equinox OSGi launcher, I get NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.setProperty(BaseDataSource.java:1030)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.setUrl(BaseDataSource.java:964)
    at org.postgresql.osgi.PGDataSourceFactory.configureBaseDataSource(PGDataSourceFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.osgi.PGDataSourceFactory.createSimpleDataSource(PGDataSourceFactory.java:127)
    at org.postgresql.osgi.PGDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(PGDataSourceFactory.java:149)
    at org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config.impl.DataSourceRegistration.createDs(DataSourceRegistration.java:108)
    at org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config.impl.DataSourceRegistration.<init>(DataSourceRegistration.java:63)
    at org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config.impl.DataSourceFactoryTracker.addingService(DataSourceFactoryTracker.java:42)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config.impl.DataSourceConfigManager.updated(DataSourceConfigManager.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$UpdateConfiguration.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1772)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:141)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After inspecting in Debugger, I've found out, the error is thrown because property `PROTOCOL_VERSION` is null. I've tried to set the variable in config file:

```
protocolVersion=3
```

but I still get the same error.

How to configure PostgreSQL DataSource in Equinox/Eclipse runtime?

I'm using PostgreSQL driver version 9.4-1200 :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems resolved with new PostgreSQL 42.1.1 driver.

A note on [PAXJDBC PostgreSQL Driver Adapter](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/PostgreSQL+Driver+Adapter) page states:

> Current postgresql versions are valid bundles and also provide a DataSourceFactory. So if you use a recent version you will not need this adapter anymore.

Try this driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting the issue [PAXJDBC-107](https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXJDBC-107). Pax-jdbc-config uses reflection to write the properties. It currently works if the datasource has a setter with an Integer parameter but not with int. I plan to fix this in the next days and do a new release.

Comment: Ok .. then it might only be an issue with the postgresql version.

Comment: It looks like it is. I'm not sure if I should write this as an answer... Nevertheless, shouldn't the buggy version be removed from Maven repository?

Comment: released artifacts are never removed from maven repositories, that's why you have the next version available. If you can't live with the latest released version, try with the latest SNAPSHOT version. If that one isn't working as planned and the project in question is an open source one, get yourself involved.